# Adding Header files to package

Tags: ros, include, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may be so elementary, but by using functions from any header file in the "include/whatever_pkg_name" folder of the package, the compiler complains about "Undefined reference to...". What step am I missing? The include files are properly called from the source code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10127/adding-header-files-to-package/) by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2011-05-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2011-05-31**:
No, it's nothing external. It's a very simple call to a function declared on a header file inside the "include" folder. I will send you the code for you to see what I'm talking about.

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-05-31**:
Looks like a linking problem. Are you calling functions from an outside package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, my problem was that I wasn't including the related .cpp files in the **CMakeLists.txt**, for example, I only had

> rosbuild_add_executable(sphereo_node src/sphereo.cpp)

which was missing the remaining source files that implement the functions in the header file *my_header.h*, such as:

> rosbuild_add_executable(sphereo_node src/sphereo.cpp **src/my_header.cpp**)

Thanks to Bill and Ivan!

---

Originally posted by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) with karma: 347 on 2011-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on 2012-12-11**:
Thanks! Searched for quite a while. Thanks for pointing out such a mistake for me. Now it seems so obvious... :)